# Get function object from stack (Frame) object

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a custom logging class for module `logging` that I called `call`. With this class I hope to place it in any function/method and it logs the function name with its arguments and all values the function was called with.

This works fine for class methods

```
Foo.bar(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, *args=(), **kwargs={'something': 4})
```

using this minimal example

```
import logging
import inspect

def call(logger):
    fname = []  # Function name including module and class
    fargs = []  # Arguments of function including positional and named arguments

    parentframe = inspect.stack()[1][0]
    module      = inspect.getmodule(parentframe)

    if module and module.__name__ != "__main__":
        fname.append(module.__name__)

    codename = parentframe.f_code.co_name

    if "self" in parentframe.f_locals:
        fname.append(parentframe.f_locals["self"].__class__.__name__)

    fobj = getattr(parentframe.f_locals["self"].__class__, codename)

    if codename != "<module>":
        fname.append(codename)

    argspec = inspect.formatargspec(*inspect.getfullargspec(fobj))
    args = argspec[1:-1].split(",")

    for arg in args:
        argkey = arg.strip().replace("*", "").split("=")[0]
        if arg == "self":
            fargs.append("self")
        else:
            fargs.append(arg.split("=")[0] + "=" + str(parentframe.f_locals[argkey]))

    del parentframe

    msg = ".".join(fname) + "(" + ",".join(fargs) + ")"
    if logger.isEnabledFor(30):
        logger.log(30, msg)


class Foo:

    def __init__(self, l):
        self.logger = l

    def bar(self, a, b, c=3, *args, **kwargs):
        call(self.logger)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.addLevelName(30, "CALL")
    logger = logging.getLogger('blub')
    logger.level = 20
    f = Foo(logger)
    f.bar(1, 2, something=4)
    print("done...")
```

My problem is when I use the same functionality on static methods or simple functions. It fails at the line where I get the function object (`fobj = getattr(parentframe.f_locals["self"].__class__, codename)`
) using `self`.

parentframe is the `Frame` object of the function in questions I presume. I have not yet found a way to get the function object from that object. Is there a way?

Answer (score 4):

Use `getattr(module, codename)` to get the function-object of functions that are not contained in classes.

Here the full code:

```py
import logging
import inspect

def call(logger):
    fname = []  # Function name including module and class
    fargs = []  # Arguments of function including positional and named arguments

    parentframe = inspect.stack()[1][0]
    module      = inspect.getmodule(parentframe)

    if module and module.__name__ != "__main__":
        fname.append(module.__name__)

    codename = parentframe.f_code.co_name

    if "self" in parentframe.f_locals:
        fname.append(parentframe.f_locals["self"].__class__.__name__)
        fobj = getattr(parentframe.f_locals["self"].__class__, codename)
    else:
        fobj = getattr(module, codename)

    if codename != "<module>":
        fname.append(codename)

    argspec = inspect.formatargspec(*inspect.getfullargspec(fobj))
    args = argspec[1:-1].split(",")

    for arg in args:
        argkey = arg.strip().replace("*", "").split("=")[0]
        if arg == "self":
            fargs.append("self")
        else:
            fargs.append(arg.split("=")[0] + "=" + str(parentframe.f_locals[argkey]))

    del parentframe

    msg = ".".join(fname) + "(" + ",".join(fargs) + ")"
    if logger.isEnabledFor(30):
        logger.log(30, msg)


class Foo:

    def __init__(self, l):
        self.logger = l

    def bar(self, a, b, c=3, *args, **kwargs):
        call(self.logger)


def boo(a, b, c=3, *args, **kwargs):
    call(logger)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.addLevelName(30, "CALL")
    logger = logging.getLogger('blub')
    logger.level = 20
    f = Foo(logger)
    f.bar(1, 2, something=4)
    boo(1, 2, something=4)
    print("done...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking ideas from both, I wrote this function to find the function object from a frame. I'm sure there's some edge cases around inherited staticmethods, and obviously any code not using the `cls` and `self` conventions for param names. This also doesn't work for lambdas... but you shouldn't be logging anything out in a lamba anyway :-P

```
def _get_func_obj(f):
    """
    Get function object from a frame. If it can't find it, return None
    """

    codename = f.f_code.co_name
    fobj = None

    try:
        if "self" in f.f_locals:  # regular method
            fobj = getattr(f.f_locals["self"].__class__, codename)
        elif "cls" in f.f_locals:  # class method
            fobj = getattr(f.f_locals["cls"], codename)
        else:
            module = inspect.getmodule(f)  # only fetch module if we need it

            if hasattr(module, codename):  # regular module level function
                fobj = getattr(module, codename)
            else:  # static method
                classes = [
                    getattr(module, name)
                    for name in dir(module)
                    if inspect.isclass(getattr(module, name))
                ]
                for cls in classes:
                    if (
                        hasattr(cls, codename)
                        and getattr(cls, codename).__code__ == f.f_code
                    ):
                        fobj = getattr(cls, codename)
                        break
        if fobj is None:
            """it's likely some nested function/method or a lambda, who logs in a lambda?"""
        return fobj
    except Exception:
        """never break logging"""
```